# Examples of things in physics which are non-rigorous and offend mathematicians

Tags: soft-question

I don't know how to make this community wiki. Anyway, what I am looking for are things in physics that offend mathematicians because of the lack of rigor. I would also like answers that mention things that were non-rigorous in the past, even if they now have a rigorous formulation or definition.

Comment: List questions, especially those without any underlying conceptual question, are generally considered off-topic here.  Beyond that, there is no real answer to this question. With the exception of overly-excitable math students, I suspect that most people understand that full rigor is neither necessary nor even desirable for most physics applications, and that there is an [entire branch of physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_physics) dedicated to worrying about the technicalities which most others gloss over. Due to their efforts, pretty much everything I can think of [...]

Comment: [...] which is used in physics has a relatively rigorous formulation somewhere.  Things that don't - path integrals, etc - are active areas of research for both communities.

Comment: See my answers to [Angular velocity of precession](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113194/37364), or [Why is force a vector?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/372380/37364). I talk about this issue.